# Python KeyError while comparing chars in dict and list

Tags: python, dictionary, frequency, keyerror

I have a problem concerning a comparison between a char key in a dict and a char within a list.
The Task is to read a text and count all beginning letters.

I have a list with chars:

```
bchars = ('i','g','h','n','h')
```

and a dict with the alphabet and frequency default to zero:

```
d = dict(dict())
  for i in range(97,123):
    d[i-97]={chr(i):0}
```

no i want to check like the following:

```
for i in range(len(bchars)):
  for j in range(len(d)):
    if(bchars[i] in d[j]):
      d[j][chr(i+97)] +=1
    else:
      d[j][chr(i+97)] +=0
```

so if the char in the list is a key at the certain position then += 1 else += zero
I thought by using a if/else statement I can bypass the KeyError.

Is there any more elegant solution for that?

Comment: Sorry, but I have tried to read and reread the question many times and I still do not quite understand what you are trying to achieve here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specific problem is that you check whether `bchars[i]` is `in d[j]`, but then the key you actually use is `chr(i+97)`.

`chr(i+97)` is the index of the `i`th character in `bchars`, but mapped to ASCII characters starting from `'a'`. Why would you want to use this as your key?

I think you really want to do:

```
for i in range(len(bchars)):
    for j in range(len(d)):
        if(bchars[i] in d[j]):
            d[j][bchars[i]] += 1
        else:
            d[j][bchars[i]] = 1
```

Note that you can't use `+=` in the `else`; remember how you *literally just checked* whether the key was there and decided it wasn't?

More broadly, though, your code doesn't make sense - it is overcomplicated and does not use the real power of Python's dictionaries. `d` looks like:

```
{0: {'a': 0}, 1: {'b': 0}, 2: {'c': 0}, ...}
```

It would be much more sensible to build a dictionary mapping character directly to count:

```
{'a': 0, 'b': 0, 'c': 0, ...}
```

then you can simply do:

```
for char in bchars:
    if char in d:
        d[char] += 1
```

Python even comes with [a class just for doing this sort of thing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

Answer (score 1):

The nested dictionary doesn't seem necessary:

```
d = [0] * 26
for c in bchars:
    d[ord(c)-97] += 1
```

You might also want to look at the `Counter` class in the `collections` module.

Answer (score 1):

```
from collections import Counter

bchars = ('i','g','h','n','h')
counts = Counter(bchars)
print(counts)
print(counts['h'])
```

prints

```
Counter({'h': 2, 'i': 1, 'g': 1, 'n': 1})
2
```